# How do I implement a messaging system for members of my website to communicate with each other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, private-messaging

I have a fully functional website, to which I want to add the ability for members to email each other, kinda like facebook, but much smaller, so I won't need their need for huge traffic.

Basically I need a starting point. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking to code this yourself?..

Comment: yeah, I am, or maybe if there are existing systems I can look at to help me?

Answer (score 2):

First step is to design the tables to store the mail objects.

One approach which works is to set up a mail "hasMany" children relationship, which basically means that a single mail object will have an id column and a self-referential parent_id column like this:

```
mail:
id , parent_id, create_time , from_user_id , to_user_id , textual_content
```

or something similar.

Comment: no i have all the tables for it already, i got the messages table and the inbox and outbox. i don't know how to start coding it though